# Mongodb compound index with sort on _id unique index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have a collection with document like:

```
{
  _id: "",
  reportId: "a",
  accountId: "",
   ....
 }
```

Now my query pattern is like:

```
db.saleReport.find({reportId: "e6044e8a", "accountId":{$in: ["a","b"] }).sort({"_id":1});
```

I have created a compound index with:

```
db.saleReport.createIndex({reportId:1,accountId:1})
```

The above index is getting used only in query stage. There is a sort stage added even to sort on `_id` field.

Should I add `_id` also as part of index? Isn't the `_id` field stored in index already to uniquely identify the record?

Comment: What did you do in the end? Was the _id index in necessary?

Comment: yes, it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> *Isn't the `_id` field stored in index already to uniquely identify the record?*

Yes this will perform sort operation, but **[Blocking Sort Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#sort-and-index-use)**, it means in memory sort operation,

**Behaviour of Blocking Sort:**

*To check if MongoDB must perform a blocking sort, append `cursor.explain()` to the query and check the explain results. If the query plan contains a **SORT** stage, then MongoDB must perform a blocking sort operation subject to the 100 megabyte memory limit.*

*If MongoDB requires using more than 100 megabytes of system memory for the blocking sort operation, MongoDB returns an error unless the query specifies `cursor.allowDiskUse()` (New in MongoDB 4.4). `allowDiskUse()` allows MongoDB to use temporary files on disk to store data exceeding the 100 megabyte system memory limit while processing a blocking sort operation.*

You can use `allowDiskUse` in find method from MongoDB 4.4, if you don't want add `_id` field in your compound index,

```
db.saleReport
  .find({reportId: "e6044e8a", "accountId":{$in: ["a","b"] })
  .allowDiskUse()
  .sort({"_id":1});
```

> *Should I add `_id` also as part of index?*

**Why intersection of `_id` and compound index is not applying?**

See **[Index Intersection and Sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort)**: *Index intersection does not apply when the `sort()` operation requires an index completely separate from the query predicate.*

Yes you can definitely add `_id` field as part of compound index, if you don't want to perform Blocking Sort or in memory sort operation,

```
db.saleReport.createIndex({reportId:1,accountId:1,_id:1});
```